# How to override value in Scala in a proper way?

Tags: scala

I have a problem with getters/setters and traits in Scala. How to get updated value of "tax"? I am overriding value of tax and i expect to return updated value of tax.
Output:

```
price: 25000.0
tax: 0.0
```

Output needed:

```
price: 25000.0
tax: 5000.0
```

Where's my problem?

```
class Car(val brand: String, val model: String, val tax: Double)

  trait Muscle extends Car {
    var _price = 0.0
    def price: Double = _price
    def price_= (value: Double): Unit = _price = value
    override val tax = 0.2 * _price
  }

val muscle = new Car("Chevrolet", "Camaro", 500.0) with Muscle
muscle.price = 25000
println("price: " + muscle.price)
println("tax: " + muscle.tax)
```

Comment: Your `_price` field is set to 0 when you first set the `tax` field, so even if you change it later, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now, but how can I reach my point?

Comment: Honestly, this doesn't seem like a great design to me, but I guess you could make it `def tax` (in both places) so it's recalculated each time.

Comment: What you exactly want to do? can you please explain

Comment: This is one of the tasks that i have to do. I need to define a class called "Car" (that has parameters: "brand", "model" and "tax". All of them read only.) and a trait: "Muscle" that has a parameter: "price". "Muscle" should override "tax" with a new "tax" value that is 20% of a "price" value.

Comment: And you can't change the design? it has to be like this only?

Comment: I can, as long as requirments that i wrote higher are met.

Comment: is that what you want to do? in my answer?

Comment: Nope, it’s the easiest way, I can agree, but in the task there has to be parameter „tax”, not „price” in the class declaration and trait must be used. Thanks for trying, but it’s a specific situation.

Comment: And i have to add that I must use getter and setter for „price” parameter too.

Answer (score 1):

Disclamer: this is not idiomatic Scala and not the best practice at all but since you've asked...

First of all logical design of these classes is confusing. The parent class defines tax which the child completely ignores while adding another field - price.

Second: mutating is usually unnecessary in Scala and using a mixin to mutate original value adds to complexity and confusion.

Anyway, the `tax` field in `Car` class is "immutable" to the callers since it's a function. We can't define a `val tax` because we intend to override it with a mutable value - Scala doesn't allow that for good reasons.

```
class Car(val brand: String, val model: String, default_tax: Double) {
    def tax: Double = default_tax
}
```

Then:

```
trait Muscle extends Car {
    private var _price = 0.0
    def price: Double = _price
    def price_= (value: Double): Unit = _price = value
    override def tax = 0.2 * _price
}
```

Test:

```
scala> val muscle = new Car("Chevrolet", "Camaro", 500.0) with Muscle
muscle: Car with Muscle = $anon$1@17b959b9

scala> muscle.price = 25000
mutated muscle.price

scala> println("price: " + muscle.price)
price: 25000.0

scala> println("tax: " + muscle.tax)
tax: 5000.0
```

Not supposed to work:

```
scala> muscle.tax = 0
              ^
       error: value tax_= is not a member of Car with Muscle
```

Tax is updated:

```
scala> muscle.price = 100
mutated muscle.price

scala> muscle.tax
res3: Double = 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making things complicated for your self you can simply do this, I am not sure this is what you want to do.

```
case class Car(brand: String, model: String, price: Double){
  val tax: Double = price * 0.2
}

object Demo1 extends App {
  val car = Car("Chevrolet", "Camaro", 25000)

  println(s"price: ${car.price}")
  println(s"tax: ${car.tax}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make `tax` a `def` so it's updated whenever `_price` is updated.

As a side-note, your entire modelling is a bit weird. A more reasonable approach would make `price` an abstract var, and you end up with something like

```
trait Muscle {
  val price: Double
  def tax = 0.2 * price
}

object MuscleCar extends Car("Chevrolet", "Camaro", 500.0) with Muscle {
   val price = 100
}
```